# Rails nested resources routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, rails-routing

I'm writing a small Ruby-on-Rails project. I have 2 models: Users and Tasks

1 task belongs to two users (author and target-user), so I in model I did:

```
    belongs_to :target, :class_name => 'User'
    belongs_to :author, :class_name => 'User'
```

Of course, Users model has

```
    has_many :posts
```

So, I want to be able to CRUD user's tasks by  url/users/:username/tasks and not to be able to  do it just by /tasks

So I removed resources :tasks from the routes.rb and added the nested resource

```
    resources :users do
      resources :tasks
    end
```

I even updated views (i.e.  edit_task_path(task) to  edit_user_task_path(task) ) and _form.html.erb
but I have an error:

```
Showing C:/Sites/todoit/app/views/tasks/index.html.erb where line #24 raised:
undefined method `task_path' for #<#<Class:0x458ce08>:0x458ad20>
```

What should I do?

---

posts index.html.erb: http://pastebin.com/DdGurSfe

Comment: Can you post the `app/views/tasks/index.html.erb` file?

Comment: Of course. Here: http://pastebin.com/DdGurSfe

Comment: As `tasks` is a nested resource you won't have a `task_path` but something like a `user_task_path`. Running `rake routes` in the console from your application's directory should give you an idea of the paths that you can use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<td><%= link_to 'Show', user_task_path(task) %></td>
# or
<td><%= link_to 'Show', [:user, task] %></td>
```

Anyway run `rake routes` to check available routes (unless you will be able to do it in mind). Cheers!